# How can I simplify this using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following function, how can I simplify it using jquery?

```
function updateCards(){
    var form = document.getElementById("sets");
    var chks = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checked = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++){
        if(chks[i].checked){
            checked.push(chks[i].value)
        }
    }

    // test code
    //alert("SELECTED SETS:"+checked);

    if (checked == ""){
        document.getElementById("all-cards").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("all-cards").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","update_cards.php?sets="+checked, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will only need to rewrite the selectors, use some DOM manipulation functions like [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and of course [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: I've looked at multiple examples and I'm still learning. Jquery and Ajax syntax looks very foreign to me and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function updateCards(){
    var $form = $('#sets'), $chks = $form.find('input:checkbox'), checked ;

    checked = $chks.map(function(){
        return this.checked ? this.value : undefined;
    }).get();

    if (checked.length == 0){
        $('#all-cards').html('');
        return;
    } 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'update_cards.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            sets: checked
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(html){
        $('#all-cards').html(html);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same function in jQuery can be written like below.

```
function updateCards() {
    var $form = $('#sets'),
        $chks = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),
        $allCards = $('#all-cards');

    var checked = $chks.map(function() {
           return  this.value
    });

    if(checked.length === 0) {
        $allCards.html('');
        return
    }
    // Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "update_cards.php?sets="+checked,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(data) {
         $allCards.html(data);
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```